# Change pending status to submitted after uploading of file in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating an assignment management system where students are uploading their assignments and the status of assignments are pending before uploading. I want to change the status when the assignment is saved at backend and change the status to submitted.

template code

```
 <tr>
                            <td>{{assignment.assignment_date}}</td>
                            <td>{{assignment.assignment_creator}}</td>
                            <td>{{assignment.assignment_title}} </td>
                            <td>
                                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'assignment' %}" method="POST">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input required type="file" name="inputFile" id="" placeholder="upload">
                                    <button>Upload</button>
                                    {{s.assignment_status}}
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td> <span class="bg-success text-white">Pending </span></td>
                        </tr>
```

views.py

```
  print('file uploaded')
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('file uploaded Post')

        uploaded_file = request.FILES['inputFile']
        print(uploaded_file)
        student = Student.objects.get(student_username=request.user)
        std_instance = student
        document = Submissions.objects.create(submitted_by=std_instance,
                                              submission_file=uploaded_file)
        document.save()
        print('saved')
```

models.py

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment_creator = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    assignment_details = models.TextField()
    assignment_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    assignment_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Submissions(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submission_file = models.FileField(null=False)
    submitted_to = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: Share your models? Do you want to add this status to the `Submissions` model or something else?

Comment: I want to change the status in the template and also in the submssion mode.

Comment: Please add the models to the question and not in the comments. Shouldn't there be a foreign key from submission to assignment?

Comment: I was thinking same but I am little confused here

Comment: How do you know which students have been assigned an assignment? I think you may have to redesign your models a bit

Answer (score 0):

I would have assignment_title as a foreign key and assignment_status in the submission model. Then you just changed assignment_status to true right before document save.

I’m assuming multiple students will be getting the same assignments.